# List d-bus registered objects from Java

Tags: java, dbus, modem

I would like to communicate with a running ModemManager (which uses D-Bus), from Java. Searching shows a lot of flame-wars because of Java not being open-source etc. Well, that's not my problem is it? I just cann't get this project started due to a lack of examples for using bus from Java. I'd be very happy to have at least a way to e.g. list registered objects (on the system bus) and their methods. From such starting pint I'll try to dive deeper to get to the ModemManager objects. This is what I have so far:

```
public interface DummyInterface extends DBusInterface
{
    public static class Connect extends DBusSignal {
      public final String address;
      public Connect(String path, String address)
                             throws DBusException{
          super(path, address);
          this.address = address;
      }
    }
  public static class Disconnect extends DBusSignal {
    public final String address;
    public Disconnect(String path, String address)
                             throws DBusException {
       super(path, address);
       this.address = address;
      }
    }
  } package com.emcatron.dbus_test;

import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusSigHandler;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusSignal;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException;

public class Client implements DBusSigHandler {
    public void handle(DBusSignal s) {
        if (s instanceof DummyInterface.Connect)
            System.out.println("Got a connect for "
                    + ((DummyInterface.Connect) s).address);
        else if (s instanceof DummyInterface.Disconnect)
            System.out.println("Got a disconnect for "
                    + ((DummyInterface.Disconnect) s).address);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating Connection");
        DBusConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DBusConnection
                    .getConnection(DBusConnection.SYSTEM);
        } catch (DBusException DBe) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to bus");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Connected to system DBUS: " + DBusConnection.SYSTEM);
        int i = 0;
        for (String name: conn.getNames()) {
            System.out.format("name: %d: %s\n", i, name);
        }
        try {
            conn.addSigHandler(DummyInterface.Connect.class,
                    new Client());
            conn.addSigHandler(DummyInterface.Disconnect.class,
                    new Client());
        } catch (DBusException DBe) {
            conn.disconnect();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

So I do get a connection, the output is something like:
    Connected to system DBUS: 0
    name: 0: :1.700

And the next time I run it, it will be 
    1.701
but: What's the next step to dive into the registered objects????

Comment: By the way, OpenJDK has been under GPL version 2 with classpath exception since 2006 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

The `getNames` call is returing the name of your own d-bus connection so it isn't useful here.

In d-bus each service has a *busname* and under that busname there are a list of *objects* and each object has a list of *interfaces*. You can use a tool such as `d-feet` to explore the busnames, objects, and interfaces on your machine.

To get to a specific interface you call `getRemoteObject` and specify the busname, objectPath, and interface class. For example

```
dbus = conn.getRemoteObject("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/", DBus.class)
```

This particular interface is the one to use to get a list of all the busnames:

```
dbus.ListNames()
```

Getting the list of objects is much harder and involves using the `org.freedesktop.Introspectable` interfaces on the root object `/` and then parsing the XML to work out what the sub-nodes are. But most services have well-known objects and interfaces so you should be able to access them directly using `getRemoteObject`.